# IllegalStateException: JBAS014531: Cache entry [...] is not in use?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, cdi, jboss7.x

I am running into a couple of Exceptions similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426193/cache-entry-not-in-use), but I think in my case it's just the result of yet another problem.

Environment: JBoss AS 7, JSF (Mojarrah + Primefaces 3.2), JPA 2 (Hibernate), EJB 3.1, CDI

I have four views with a quite similar structure. Three of them work just fine, the last one is having this problem. It consists of a `p:inputText` (p=Primefaces) and a `p:dataTable` component.

```
<p:inputText id="barcode" label="Barcode" value="#{testBean.barcode}"
 required="true" validator="#{testBean.validateBarcode}">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="barcode" />

<p:dataTable [...]/>
```

I expect the form to be submitted via Ajax when the user entered the barcode (either by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or by leaving the textfield). My backing bean is `@Named @ViewScoped @Stateful` and is using an `EntityManager` in extended mode (as mentioned in one of [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426193/cache-entry-not-in-use)).

**The Problem:** Apparently the form gets submitted twice at the same time:

1. as Ajax POST request -> on Thread #5
2. as plain POST request (non-Ajax) -> on Thread #6

My logfile states:

```
21:58:09,294 Information [net.svv.servlet.RequestLogger] (http--127.0.0.1-7080-5) POST /tat/tat/test.jsf
21:58:09,302 Information [net.svv.servlet.RequestLogger] (http--127.0.0.1-7080-6) POST /tat/tat/test.jsf
```

causing the following Exception:

```
21:58:09,334 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http--127.0.0.1-7080-6) ARJUNA016029: SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion - failed for org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor$StatefulSessionSynchronization@67dc20fd with exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014531: Cache entry {[-106, 108, 121, 57, -117, -54, 77, -75, -66, 78, -95, 39, 21, -84, -2, 118]} is not in use
```

a couple of times, sometimes even ~20 times.

Then the HTTP response:

```
21:58:11,892 Information [net.svv.servlet.RequestLogger] (http--127.0.0.1-7080-5) response: 200 text/xml;charset=UTF-8 (2598 msec)
21:58:11,924 Information [net.svv.servlet.RequestLogger] (http--127.0.0.1-7080-6) response: 200 text/html;charset=UTF-8 (2622 msec)
```

As I understand it, the view is requested twice within the same session, causing the exceptions. So my question is, why is the form submitted twice when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? And why does this behavior only occur on one of four views? (the others have the same `<p:inputText />` components for barcodes)

ps: I am aware of the possibility to check for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key event using JavaScript, so it's not a question of how to avoid it, but more a question of *why* the form is submitted twice. Also: some of the barcode scanners we use send the <kbd>Enter</kbd> char to submit the data.

pps: I only want the Ajax form submission to avoid resubmission on pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Thanks for the interest in reading the whole story ;)

---

Full stack trace:

```
1:58:09,334 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http--127.0.0.1-7080-6) ARJUNA016029: SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion - failed for org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor$StatefulSessionSynchronization@67dc20fd with exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014531: Cache entry {[-106, 108, 121, 57, -117, -54, 77, -75, -66, 78, -95, 39, 21, -84, -2, 118]} is not in use
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.cache.impl.backing.NonPassivatingBackingCacheImpl.release(NonPassivatingBackingCacheImpl.java:134) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.cache.impl.backing.NonPassivatingBackingCacheImpl.release(NonPassivatingBackingCacheImpl.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.cache.spi.impl.AbstractCache.release(AbstractCache.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.cache.spi.impl.AbstractCache.release(AbstractCache.java:39) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.releaseInstance(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:197) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.access$200(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor$StatefulSessionSynchronization.afterCompletion(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:271) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:96)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:402)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:103)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at net.svv.tat.TestBean$$$view341.getTableModel(Unknown Source) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1928.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_04]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at net.svv.tat.TestBean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.getTableModel(TestBean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java) [classes:]
at net.svv.tat.TestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getTableModel(TestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1930.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_04]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:786) [primefaces-3.2.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1401) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:163) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:362) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.findComponent(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:440) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreDynamicAdd(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:363) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreDynamicActions(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:314) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:281) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at net.svv.servlet.RequestLogger.doFilter(RequestLogger.java:81) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
```

Comment: Have you tried just plain JSF2 tags? Maybe it's a PrimeFaces bug.